# Clarification: how to get the following asymptotics

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, asymptotics

I'm having some trouble justifying some steps in a paper.

> Let $a_n$ be an increasing sequence of integers satisfying $n! \le a_n \le 2(n!)$, and let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a function satisfying
>   $$f(2a_n+1) = \frac{1}{2}(2a_n+1)(2a_n+2)+na_n-\frac{1}{2}(n-1)(n-2).$$
>
> Let $l:=2h_n+1$. The paper claims $$f(l) \le \frac{l(l+1)+l\cdot g(l)}{2} \tag{*},$$
>   where $g(l) \sim \frac{\log l}{\log \log l}$ as $l \to \infty$. Moreover,
>   $$f(l) \ge \frac{l^2 + l \cdot O\left(\frac{\log l}{\log \log l}\right)}{2}.\tag{**}$$

My attempts:

If we replace $2a_n+1$ with $l$, we have
$$f(l) \le \frac{l(l+1)}{2} + na_n \le \frac{l(l+1)}{2}+\frac{l\cdot n}{2}.$$
So we need something like $n \sim g(l)$. I have an intuition for where the expression for $g$ comes from, but it is extremely imprecise. I use the symbol $\leftrightsquigarrow$ to denote similar growth.
\begin{align*}
l:=2a_n+1 &\leftrightsquigarrow n!\\
l &\leftrightsquigarrow n^n & \text{Stirling's approx.?}\\
\log l &\leftrightsquigarrow n \log n\\
\log \log l &\leftrightsquigarrow \log (n \log n)\\
g(l)\sim \frac{\log l}{\log \log l} &\leftrightsquigarrow n\frac{\log n}{\log (n \log n)} \sim n
\end{align*}

There are several issues:

- something is lost in Stirling's approximation (it is not true that $n^n \sim n!$).
- I am not sure how to rigorously express $\leftrightsquigarrow$. In particular, there is a constant factor lurking somewhere in the work toward $g(l) \leftrightsquigarrow n$, but (*) shows no such constant.

As for the lower bound, I have no idea. The only difference from the upper bound is the change of $l+1$ to $l$ and the $\sim$ to $O(\cdot)$. This suggests that both bounds are pretty tight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting $\nu = 2a_n+1$ and taking $\eta$ as the inverse map of $\theta:n\to a_n$ we have:
$$f(\nu)=\frac{\nu(\nu+1)}{2}+\frac{\nu-4}{2}\eta((\nu-1)/2)-\frac{1}{2}\eta((\nu-1)/2)^2-1,$$
hence we just need tight asymptotics for the $\eta$ function. Since:$$\left(\frac{m+1}{e}\right)^{m+1}\geq 2m!\geq\theta(m)\geq m!\geq\left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^m,$$
we must have:
$$\left(\frac{\eta(t)}{e}\right)^{\eta(t)}\leq t\leq \left(\frac{\eta(t)+1}{e}\right)^{\eta(t)+1},$$
so:
$$ \eta(t)\left(\log\eta(t)-1\right)\leq \log t\leq (\eta(t)+1)\left(\log(\eta(t)+1)-1\right).\tag{1}$$
To estimate the root of $u(\log u-1)-\log t=0$ we can exploit the convexity of the LHS.

The Newton's method gives that the root of such equation is:
$$\frac{\log t}{\log \log t}+O\left(\frac{\log t\,(\log\log\log t)}{(\log \log t)^2}\right),$$
hence
$$ \eta(t)=\Theta\left(\frac{\log t}{\log \log t}\right)$$
due to $(1)$.

Comment: The bound $2m! \le ((m+1)/e)^{m+1}$ only works for large $m$, correct? Also, did you get the precise asymptotics from Newton's method be obtained computationally or analytically?

Comment: Yes, that bound works only for (moderately) large $m$. The asymptotics for the Newton bound are derived by starting the iteration in $x_0=\frac{\log t}{\log \log t}$ and exploiting the fact that $\frac{d}{du}u(\log u-1)=\log u$.